# Add breaks to format text into a standard block

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I am trying to format this text using regular expressions in bold and italics so that is it looks like the standard version with breaks:

Original:

***SPECIAL USE PERMIT #2011-0016 605 LITTLE STREET SINGLE FAMILY DWELLING Public hearing and consideration of a request to construct a single family dwelling on a substandard
lot; zoned R-2-5/Single and Two Family.  Applicant:  Brian Thomas***

Standard version with breaks:

```
SPECIAL USE PERMIT #2011-0016
605 LITTLE STREET
SINGLE FAMILY DWELLING
Public hearing and consideration of a request to construct a single family dwelling on a 
substandard lot; zoned R-2-5/Single and Two Family.  Applicant:  Brian Thomas
```

Comment: You should be able to find the pattern based on #number-number.  However, You would need to specify in the regex what the possible values can be other than 'SINGLE FAMILY DWELLING'.  Are caps always used as in your example?  Without this information, I don't think there's a solution regex can provide.

Comment: Why regexp and not a general solution, i.e. split on first whitespace after `#` and then split on first whitespace after word with all capitals as a start

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you avoid using `<br>` and instead opt for some versatile tagging like `<div class="address">...</div>`. If you later decide to change your display or export your data, this will be useful.

Extracting the first block is easy `/^(.+\s\d{4}-\d+)\s+/` but there's no simple way to split between the address and the caption ("STREET" and "SINGLE"). I believe you'll have to build an heuristic, but be careful to test it well. Take a good sample of data. Then write some unit tests for functions that extract blocks:

```
// with PHPunit.
// You should use @provider for testing on multiple input data
// And an Extract class with methods would be cleaner than functions.
function titleTest() {
    assertEquals(
        array("SPECIAL USE PERMIT #2011-0016", "605 LITTLE STREET..."),
        extractTitle("SPECIAL...")
    );
}
function addressTest() {
    list($title, $rest) = extractTitle("SPECIAL...");
    assertEquals(
        array("605 LITTLE STREET", "SINGLE..."),
        $rest
```

Once you have tests that fail, you can build your function extractAddress() until it succeeds on every sample. It will probably combine several ways, e.g. a list of caption values /SINGLE|.../, a list of address' end /STREET|DRIVE|.../

Answer (score 0):

I think I've a very easy solution for this.
The original text may have linebreaks, like `\n \r`, and you need to convert them in `<br>`.
If my theory is correct you should be able to format the text by doing this:

```
str_replace("\n", "<br>", $string);
```

Try it out and let me know if it works.